# Z Tests across multiple Samples to produce Probabilities?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

So I've a problem I'm trying to solve. I'm more of a coder than a stats guy so this may be very basic!

Movie A rated 5.5 with 10 ratings(5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6,5,6), movie B rated 5.44 with 9 ratings (4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,5), movie C rated 5.33 with 9 ratings (2,3,8,9,2,3,8,9,4)

What is the probability that C is rated higher than A or B when all three have 10 ratings. We are waiting on two ratings to be added - 1 for B and 1 for C. A is finished as it has ten already.

Normal distribution can be assumed as being true for the three movies.

I know the method of using a Z Score to work out the probability of an individual movie being above, below or in between a certain rating ranges. But when comparing two or more ratings how do you work out the probabilities as its a constantly moving target?
With my programming hat on the simplest method I can think of is a brute force method of looping through all combinations of Z Scores relative to each other but I imagine this won't scale well at all. My question can this be done and what is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean to ask about the probability that C is rated higher than A or B once all three movies have 1000 votes?

Comment: Meaningful comparisons would require information on the variability of scores that went into each rating. For example is summary rating 7.4 mainly from 7's and 8's or do many individuals rate it as 0 and few more as 10? In the former case, 7.4 may differ significantly from 6.7; in the latter case, maybe not.

Comment: Computing a $Z$-score requires a population mean and a population standard deviation. But there are other ways to compare ratings that do not use $Z$-scores. See my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This Answer was for a quite different original
version of the question.**

First, here is an example comparing two movies:
For Movie X, 1000 subjects give an average
rating of 7.0 and, for Movie Y, 1100 subjects
give an average rating of 4.9.

Summaries of individual scores for the two movies
are given below:

```
summary(x)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  3.000   6.000   7.000   7.049   8.000  10.000 
summary(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   4.000   5.000   4.977   6.000   9.000
```

Boxplots of the scores (X bottom) show that about half
of the scores for X were 6, 7 or 8 and about half of the scores
for Y were 4, 5, or 6. The non-overlapping
'notches' in the sides of the boxes suggest that
there is statistically significant difference
in the popularity of the two movies.

boxplot(x, y, horizontal=T, notch=T, col="skyblue2")

[image]

For small samples, the Wilcoxon Rank Sum test has
difficulty giving definitive results, if there are
many individuals with the same scores ("ties"), as is often
true of movie ratings. However,
for large samples, results are reliable. The P-value
very near $0$ shows strong evidence of a statistically
significant difference. (Results from R.)

```
wilcox.test(x,y)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test 
        with continuity correction

data:  x and y
W = 902510, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

However, if 900 ratings for Movie W are much more diverse
than for Movie Y, it is more difficult to say which
movie is better, even though both have similar median ratings
(both around 5).

```
summary(w)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   3.000   5.000   4.991   7.000   9.000
```

Boxplots (W on bottom) show overlapping notches. We
can say the scores are more diverse for Movie W, but it
is more complicated to try to claim one movie is more
popular than the other.

```
boxplot(w, y, horizontal=T, notch=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

A Wilcoxon test is looking for a difference in 'location'
and finds no difference at the 5% level of significance.

```
wilcox.test(y,w)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test 
        with continuity correction

data:  y and w
W = 494870, p-value = 0.992
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

If the people who really like Movie W express
their opinions more loudly than the the the ones
who hate it, Movie W might turn out to make more
money than Movie Y.

---

*Note:* Here is R code for sampling the fictitious
scores for Movies W, X, and Y.

```
set.seed(2011)
x = rbinom(1000, 10, .7)
y = rbinom(1100, 10, .5)
w = sample(1:10, 900, rep=T)
```

Comment: This is a straightforward example of how to tell if one move has significantly higher/lower ratings than another, but this doesn't seem to address the OP's specific problem. The question is given a set of additional ratings drawn from the known distribution of ratings for each movie, how likely is it that the average rating for one movie is higher than another? As movies approach the magic 1000th review, the rating can change by less and less.

Comment: Two movies with 999 reviews each may have scores that are not significantly different from each other at 7.61 and 7.64, but there is a 100% chance that the second movie still has a higher average rating after one more review comes in for each movie.

Comment: @paudro.  In my answer, I have tried to show the importance of variability in deciding whether one movie is 'better' than another. You say "Movie A rated 7.4 with 200 ratings, movie B rated 5.9 with 50 ratings, movie C rated 6.7 with 800 ratings" and then ask whether the ratings may change order at 1000 'votes'. Is that assuming that the population has not changed opinion in the meanwhile? Do you mean _barely_ changing order (from 7.61 and 7.64 to 7.63 and 7.62? Or do you mean a change in _stat. significance_ from < to >? Those are very different issues, so we need to know which is important.

Comment: @BruceET I suppose the 1st question is what is the probability Movie B ends up with a rating of 7.5 or higher, to have a higher rating than A. C is unlikely to reach that score as it is 80% complete. If I solve that I can have a probability for Movie B having the highest score. The second part: In reality though 7.5 isn't guaranteed to be the highest score as movie A can change still. Movie A could end up being 7.1 or 8.0 for instance. If it ends up being 8.0 I will have incorrect answer. So how do I account for both simultaneously

Comment: Maybe start w/ 2 movies A & B. Let A have lower avg score at $n = 400,$ B larger avg at $n=900.$ Look at history of individual ratings for each to date. Estimate $\mu_A, \sigma_A, \mu_B, \sigma_B$ from data.  How many pts does A need to catch B w/ 600 more? Assume normality. Find probability of catching up. // But B avg may gain meanwhile. Assume A and B gain votes at same rate. Predict B avg at 1500. How many extra pts does A need to barely win? Look at _extra_ total for A at 1000 vs B at 1500. Look at diff of two extra totals of pts; diff of two normals is norm. // Maybe check w/ simulation.

Comment: I will reframe and edit this question shortly as I can see I have an unintended level of complexity in it. The bit I am interested in is the relative probabilities and that portion is blurred by the number of ratings. Thanks all for you help

Comment: In practice, the most fundamental difficulty may be that the popularity of movies can fluctuate as people read reviews and hear from friends who have seen the movie. Looking at some device like 'control charts', used for quality management in some industries, might alert you if popularity of a particular movie is changing. // I see that the new version of your question really is quite different from the original.

Comment: @BruceET Yeah I know - sorry about that it only dawned on me when I was receiving replies! I suppose the lesson for me is knowing precisely the question you are trying to ask is a prerequisite and a skill in itself. Thanks for your comments they a much appreciated